# Why does the uniformly continuity and existence of right derivative implies the differentiabilty?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-continuity

Assume $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous function and has a right derivative $f'_+:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ which is also uniformly continuous. Where $f'_+$ is define by 
$$f'_+(x) = \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

> Prove or disprove that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: f' is uniformly continous  in all $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes on all $\mathbb R$

Comment: What have you tried (and seen in class/your textbook, that you can use) 
 before?

Comment: Also, relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418737/continuous-right-derivative-implies-differentiability

Comment: Hint: prove Rolle's theorem with $f_+^\prime$, then the mean value theorem, then your result.