# Proof that a continuous function with continuous right derivatives is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

I am looking at the proof given on this question given by "23rd". [Continuous right derivative implies differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418737/continuous-right-derivative-implies-differentiability)

I asked in a comment a question about 5 months ago, but didn't recieve a reply, so I am asking here instead. I have one statement in the proof I dont understand, I have marked it bold, could you please explain it to me? It is the statement "Then from $c\in E_\delta $ and $m\le g(c)\le M$ it is easy to see that $c<b$ is impossible".

*Here is what the person who asked the question wanted to prove:*

> Let $f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and have right derivatives at each point in the domain, with the right derivative function being continuous.  Then $f$ is differentiable.
> Let us denote the right derivative of $f$ by $g$.

*Here is the proof by "23rd":*

Let us denote the right derivative of $f$ by $g$.

> **Lemma:** Given $a<b$ and $m\le M$, if $m\le g\le M$ on $[a,b]$, then  $$m\le\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\le M.$$

**Proof:** Define
$$L(a)=g(a)\quad\text{and}\quad L(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a},\ x\in(a,b].$$
By definition, $L$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and it suffices to show that for every $\delta>0$,
$$E_\delta:=\Big\{x\in[a,b]\,\Big|\, m-\delta\le L(y)\le M+\delta, \forall y\in[a,x] \Big\}=[a,b].$$
By definition and the continuity of $L$, we know that $E_\delta=[a,c]$ for some $c\in[a,b]$, and from $m\le g(a)\le M$ we know $c>a$. **Then from $c\in E_\delta $ and $m\le g(c)\le M$ it is easy to see that $c<b$ is impossible**. Therefore, $c=b$ and the lemma follows. $\quad\square$

---

Now let us show that $f$ is differentiable for any $x>0$. Since $g$ is continuous, given $0<h<x$, we can define
$$m_h=\min_{y\in[x-h,x]}g(y),\quad M_h=\max_{y\in[x-h,x]}g(y),$$
and we know that
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}m_h=\lim_{h\to 0^+}M_h=g(y).$$
Due to the lemma, for $a=x-h$, $b=x$, $m=m_h$ and $M=M_h$, we have
$$m_h\le\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}\le M_h.$$
Let $h\to 0^+$, it follows that the left derivative of $f$ at $x$ exists and is equal to $g(x)$, i.e. $f$ is differentiable at $x$. $\quad\square$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $c<b$.  Remember $m\leq g\leq M$ implies the right-derivative at $c$ satisfies
$$
m\leq\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}\leq M,
$$
i.e.,
$$
m-\delta\leq\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}\leq M+\delta
$$
for all $0<h<\eta$, some $\eta$.  Hence
$$
\frac{f(c+h)-f(a)}{c+h-a}=\dfrac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}\cdot\frac{c-a}{c-a+h}+\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}\cdot\frac{h}{c-a+h}
$$
is a convex combination of two numbers in $[m-\delta,M+\delta]$ and hence is also in $[m-\delta,M+\delta]$, for all $0<h<\eta$.  This contradicts the definition of $c$.

Comment: Thank you very much!